# Can you use a reference operator with a fuction?

Tags: c++

so i recently started learning about reference (&) and dereference (*) operators in c++ and i have a question.

So, let's say i have a hypothetical function:

```
int fooBar(int foo, int bar)
{
    return foo+bar;
}
```

Could i possibly call that function like a regular variable with a reference operator (&)?

something like this:

```
int normalFunction(int &referencedFunction())
{
    return referencedFunction(someVariable);
}
```

Comment: & as an operator is the address-of operator. Declaring a reference doesn't use any operators. Anyway, are you asking whether it's possible to have a reference to a function like you can have a pointer to one?

Comment: Exactly. More specifically, this is actually for a project i have to create a simple 2D graphing API. I have a function to draw a bresenham line, but since i need the API to be portable, i want the programmer to be able to define the plot-pixel function.

Comment: In C (and C-like C++), you'd normally do that with a function pointer. However, C++ often has better options. A [template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) might work better for you.

Comment: how does `fooBar` related to `normalFunction` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pass a function to another function. The simplest way to do this is:

```
#include <functional>
// ...

int normalFunction( std::function<int()> referenced_function )
{
    return referenced_function();
}
```

The template parameter to `std::function` is the return type, followed by the parameter list in parentheses. `int()` means function returning int and taking no arguments.

Comment: I didn't know that a function could be a standard type... huh. I'll have to look more into that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. and they have the same semantics as a function pointer when used.

You can pass a function reference like this:

```
int foo_bar(int x, int y){return x + y;}

int pass_func(int(&f)(int, int)){
    return f(some_var, some_other_var);
}
```

But a nicer way to do this in C++ is to use a template parameter:

```
template<typename Functor>
int pass_func(Functor &&f){
    return f(some_var, some_other_var);
}
```

Then you can pass function pointers/references as well as function *objects* like `std::function` and lambda expressions. (or anything with `int operator()(int, int)` defined)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int func(int value) {return 5 + value;}

int func2(int (*fp)(int)) { //pointer to function
return fp(5);
}

int func3(int (&fp)(int)) {
  return fp(5);
}
```

---

```
int main() {

  std:: cout << func2(func) << "\n" ;
  std:: cout << func3(func) << "\n" ;

}
```

g++ output

```
10
10
```